# "are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?" but the namespace and reference are correct

Tags: wpf, reference, using, directive

I've got the following error when builing my project.

The type or namespace name 'OvuMenu' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

But I have put a using in my code and a reference to the dll.
It is a WPF application that exists of 3 projects.

I checked the references, even intellisense works when I put the using directive in the page.

thanks,

Filip

Comment: Could you post some of the offending code?

Comment: Would be better if you put the code, it could be conflicting names.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

using '.net 4.0 Framework' instead of '.net 4.0 framework client profile' is the solution.

Filip